# Assign content to multiple blocks inside a mixin which generates a nested HTML structure dynamically in Jade?

Tags: node.js, code-generation, pug, mixins, templating

I want to create the following HTML structure

```
<div class="outerspace">
    <div class="inner1"><p>Inner1 content</p></div>
    <div class="inner2"><p>Inner2 content</p></div>
    <div class="inner3"><p>Inner3 content</p></div>
    (...)
</div>
```

while the number of inner `divs` may vary.

**Example 1:**

---

I could create two mixins - an `òuterspace` and an `ìnner` mixin, nest them by using the `block`keyword and place different content for each inner div element:

```
mixin outerspace()
    div.outerspace
        block

mixin inner($number)
    div(class="inner" + $number)
        block

//- call the mixins
+outerspace()
    +inner(1)
        p Inner1 content
    +inner(2)
        p Inner3 content
    +inner(3)
        p Inner3 content
    ...
```

**Example 2:**

---

This example tries to do the same with a single mixin:

```
mixin nested_structure($number)
    div.outerspace
        each item in $number
            div(class="inner" + item)
                block

//- call the mixin
+nested_structure([1, 2, 3])
    p Inner content
```

This results in the same structure as described above but assigns the same content to each of the generated blocks:

```
<div class="outerspace">
    <div class="inner1"><p>Inner content</p></div>
    <div class="inner2"><p>Inner content</p></div>
    <div class="inner3"><p>Inner content</p></div>
</div>
```

---

Question: How could I use **Example 2** to generate the needed HTML structure but assign a different content to each of the inner div elements at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just put the "p Inner content" line inside the mixin?

```
mixin nested_structure($number)
    div.outerspace
        each item in $number
            div(class="inner" + item)
                p Inner#{item} content 

//- call the mixin
+nested_structure([1, 2, 3])
```

This will output:

```
<div class="outerspace">
    <div class="inner1"><p>Inner1 content</p></div>
    <div class="inner2"><p>Inner2 content</p></div>
    <div class="inner3"><p>Inner3 content</p></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not really. That was just an artificial example. There might be more than just a single ```<p>``` element and the content for each ```<div>``` element might differ, too.

Comment: How do you want to create that dynamic content? If you want to create it with a mixin, can't you just call it from the nested_structure-mixin?